# Console.Error output bind to common.logging or log4net output system

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, console.writeline

I have an assembly that writes all logs at `Console.Out`/`Console.Error`.
Now, i want to map this output streams to the one of my loggers.

So, then if i write:

```
Console.Error.WriteLine("error");
LogManager.GetLogger("logger_name").Error(error2);
```

"error" and "error2" messages should appear in one file.
How can i do that?